# Basic Search using the WHERE clause mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am fairly new to PHP and mysql and was wondering if I could get some help with my code for searching my database and returning the results.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die ("could not connect to db");
}

if (!mysql_select_db("site", $con)) {
    die ("Could not connect to table");
}

$search = $_POST["text"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM torrents WHERE name ='$search'"); //or LIKE instead of =

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['name']; 
}

?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Right now the code works error free but has no output. open to all changes and advice.

Comment: When you run the query do you have any results? Maybe there is no row with given criteria.

Comment: If it's error free, what's the problem? Are the table populated?

Comment: Maybe you have no rows, no results.

Comment: As an aside, I realize you are just learning this, but be aware this looks highly susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.  Consider looking into mysql_real_escape_string and the related notes on usage, or appropriate alternatives.

Comment: I know the code is vulnerable to injections; that's on my to do list to learn. Thanks for pointing that out though, your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

three things to start with

- Never connect with mysql db using root as username
- $search should be filtered with possible sql injections so use mysql_real_escape_string to protect your self from SQL injections
- third, try printing your query before you execute it so that you know what values are getting passed in your query. or use `trigger_error` function to see if there are any errors in your query

so a line of your code can be rewritten as

```
 $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search); 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM torrents WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

This will give you insight on whats happening

Comment: thanks, I made those changes but still get nothing. No errors or results printed. I think I am using the mysql_fetch_array wrong. Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: your use of function mysql_fetch_array is Ok. i dont see any problem with it. one thing you can do is to print your query with echo and then try to execute it directly in mysql session either from command line or any GUI tool for mysql to see what it returns. try to see if atleast there is something in $result with `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);echo $num_rows;` see what this prints.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `mysql_error()` and check if there is any error in the query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM torrents WHERE name ='$search'")
          or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

If the query is successfully probably table does not have any matching row.

If you don't want exact match and wants a near by match you can use the `LIKE` clause instead of `=`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM torrents WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'")
              or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Last thing but not least escape the string with `mysql_real_escape_string` function before appending them in SQL query.

Comment: thanks, I made these changes along with what Jaspreet Chahal mentioned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'`
2. Use full index search (since 5.6 it only works on MyISAM engine) to speed search queries instead of `LIKE`. [MySql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)
3. Google for SQLInjection.
4. Use Object Oriented driver like [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/book.pdo.php)

Comment: thanks, I'll have to look into MyISAM and PDO. I'll try to used them when I eventually rewrite my search.

Answer (score -1):

although Click already nailed "works error free" problem, here is your code with some improvements.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("site"));

if (isset($_GET["text"])) { // you have to use GET method for the search
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["text"]); // an essential thing
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM torrents WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['name']; 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no $_GET, the user is retrieving $_POST data.

Comment: connecting to mysql db as root! my foot! you should always run your queries as less privileged user and `$search = $_GET["text"];` is wrong

Comment: @mlinuxgada yet he SHOULD use GET

Comment: @JaspreetChahal on my localhost I am always using root, I see not a problem here.

Comment: @col Ok you see no problem with using `root`, WRONG ADVICE, you are taking it for granted that a user may not be prone to SQL injections and command like DROP on you mysql could not be possible.

Comment: I am never useing root on the production, if it's your concern, thank you.